# Having trouble with bubble sort Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm try realize **bubble sort** and it's doesn't work! Help me find a problem.

Code:

```
public class Main {   

  public static int e=0;
    public static int arraylength;
    public static int[] array = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
            array[i]=random.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
        }   
        arraylength=array.length;
        for (int i =0;i<arraylength;i++) {
            arraylength--;
            for (int j = 0; j < arraylength - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    e = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = e;
                }
            } 
        }   
    }
}
```

Console:

Input arr: 5 1 5 4 7 8 7 7 2 8

Output: 1 4 5 2 5 7 7 7 8 8

```
public class Main {

    public static int e=0;
    public static int arraylength;
    public static int[] array = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
            array[i]=random.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        arraylength=array.length;
        for (int i =0;i<arraylength;i++) {
            arraylength--;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    e = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = e;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
            System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Input arr:  7 7 4 1 2 9 6 4 9 6

Output: 1 2 4 4 6 6 7 7 9 9

It works,but sometimes:

Input arr:  5 2 2 3 9 6 7 7 0 6

Output: 2 2 3 0 5 6 6 7 7 9

Comment: I don't see the variable `array` initialized/declared.

Comment: What part of bubble sort requires you to modify the end conditions (the array length variable)?

Comment: https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/post_images/187/5a3/929/1875a3929dd14c8ea5ff4ccc3d0db9bd.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i =0; i<arraylength; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i =0; i<array.length; i++) {
```

The outer loop needs to run once for every element in the array, and you cannot do that with the `arraylength` variable because you are decreasing its value i.e. after the first iteration, `arraylength` no longer equals `array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int e=0;
public static int arraylength;
public static int[] array = new int[10];

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Random random = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
        array[i]=random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    arraylength = array.length;
    for (int i =0;i<arraylength;i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < arraylength - i; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                e = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = e;
            }
        }
    }
    for (final int element : array) {
        System.out.print(" " + element);
    }
}
```

you don't need to decrease the value of arraylength  every time you loop on the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static int e=0;
    public static int[] array = new int[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
            array[i]=random.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        for (int i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                    e = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = e;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;++i){
            System.out.print(" "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The line

```
arraylength--;
```

is causing the problem. You don't need to alter the value as it is affecting the working of the for loop.